# Error handling from external request class

Tags: laravel, authentication

In the login system I'm creating in Laravel (Version 5.2), the registration request is passed on to the `RegistrationRequest` class, which contains the validation logic like this:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        "username" => "required|min:3|unique:users",
        "password" => "required|min:6|confirmed",
        "email" => "required|confirmed|email|unique:users",
    ];
}
```

which is then passed on to the `postRegistration` function:

```
public function postRegistration(RegistrationRequest $request) {
    $this->user->username = $request->input('username');
    $this->user->mail = $request->input('email');
    $this->user->password = password_hash($request->input('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $this->user->save();

    $this->auth->login($this->user);
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

All kind of basic stuff, now the problem that I have is that I have no idea how to show an error when my username is for example 2 characters long.

I know that normally, I'd do

`return redirect('/registration)->withInput()->withErrors(["errorHere" => "value"]);`

but since the validation rules are external, I have no clue how to pass those to a view.

I searched some forums and the docs, but I couldn't find anything clear on it.

Is there a way to show these errors, preferably with the `withInput()` method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the Docs from [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors):

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

**EDIT**: Didn't notice the author itself answered the question until I refreshed the page.

Comment: @WesleyPeeters Do you mind accepting this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

So exactly one minute after asking this, a friend messaged me and told me that i could just do the following:

```
@if (count($errors))
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{ { $error } }</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```